# Filtering Entities Based on the type "PERSON", "ORG" etc in Spacy

Tags: spacy

After creating a `nlp` pipeline from `spacy`. Passed the doc into the pipeline.
Am trying to filter the entities based on the Type of it.

```
for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text)
```

What would be the code to filter just the `PERSON` or `ORG` from the ents list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for ent in doc.ents:
    if ent.label_ in ["PERSON", "ORG"]:
        print(ent.text)
```

See also https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#named-entities-101 for an overview of the relevant properties available from NER.

Answer (score 0):

or,

```
filter(lambda e: e.label_ in ["PERSON", "ORG"], doc.ents)
```